# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client Registering user in node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, passport.js, registration

Hi im trying to register an user with Node JS, Passport and csrfToken(MongoDB with azure as DB). Im getting error ***Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client*** trying access on register page.

This is my route user.js for user registration

```
// route to register page
router.get('/register', (req, res, next)=> {
  const messages = req.flash('error');
  res.render('register',{csrfToken: req.csrfToken, messages: messages, hasErrors: messages.length > 0});

});
//direct to profile if registration is successful
router.post('/register', passport.authenticate('local.register',{
  failureRedirect: '/register',
  failureFlash: true
}),
//after succesful registration move on to either profile or checkout pg
(req, res, next)=>{
  if (req.session.oldUrl){
    const oldUrl = req.session.oldUrl;
    req.session.oldUrl = null;
    res.redirect(oldUrl);
  }else {
      res.redirect('/user/profile');
  }
});
```

What im doing wrong? In case I attach the complete error message:
*

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\views\layout.hbs: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at done (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1004:10)
    at C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\hbs\lib\hbs.js:123:11
    at Object.done (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\hbs\lib\async.js:74:20)
    at C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\hbs\lib\hbs.js:118:20
    at C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\hbs\lib\hbs.js:99:11
    at Object.done (C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\hbs\lib\async.js:74:20)
    at C:\Users\aless\Desktop\js_cart-master\node_modules\hbs\lib\hbs.js:94:20
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3)
```

UPDATE in case error might be in passport:

```
passport.use('local.register', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'username',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, (req, username, password, done)=> {
  User.findOne({'username': username}, (err, user)=>{
    if (err){
      console.log("Errore utente");
      return done(err);
    }
    if (user){
      console.log("Errore utente usato");
      return done(null, false, {message:'Email is already in use'});

    }
    console.log("User " + username +"\nnome " + req.body.nome+ "\nsurname " + req.surname + "\nAge " + req.age + "\nemail " + req.email + "\npassword " + password);
    const newUser = new User();
    newUser.username = username;
    newUser.name = req.body.nome;
    newUser.surname = req.body.surname;
    newUser.age = req.body.age;
    newUser.email = req.body.email;
    newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
    newUser.save((err, result)=>{
      if (err){
        return done(err);
      }
      else return done(null, newUser);
    });
  });
}));
```

UPDATE 2: https://github.com/AlessioCasolaro/temprepo Here is full code

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I dont have enough reputation to comment to clarify things, so I have to make it an answer. but can you check your auth middleware? This was a mistake I had where I was sending a response in my Auth middleware.

```
module.exports.isAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
    // res.status(200).json({ user: req.user, auth: true });
  } else {
    return res.status(401).json({ auth: false, msg: "Here" });
  }
};
```

As such, I commented out the issue I had where I was sending a response in this middleware.

This was my Stack Q where I found my issue.

[My Server keeps crashing if User refreshes too much or Quick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69938867/my-server-keeps-crashing-if-user-refreshes-too-much-or-quick)

Comment: My user.js seems correct i don't understand why it show this error when I open my registration page.

This is my auth

`function isLoggedin(req, res, next){
  if (req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect('/');
}


function notLoggedin(req, res, next){
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()){
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect('/');
}`

Comment: Just know, right off the bat, with this error, it means you are using "res" or any other type of "response"  twice in the same route. Now with that being said, can you edit your Question and include your  other middleware?

Comment: https://codepen.io/beargrillz99/project/editor/ZzWvLE thats all in this link. Im crying with this code

Comment: Also while I'm looking at this, what helps me find the issue is throwing console logs in each step of the route to find out which part of the route is the issue. I'm not sure if that is good advice, but It helps me so much.

Comment: Do you have a github? I'd love to fork this and figure out the issue. I'm not as experienced as others on here, but I'm very comfortable with this issue since I've had it so often in the past

Comment: Here is it https://github.com/AlessioCasolaro/temprepo

Comment: do you have news?

Comment: Sorry! I got busy today, I got your project running on my end, and I'm currently trying to duplicate that error. Respond back to me as soon as you can

Comment: I find out that it is a problem caused by Azure Cosmos db limited on 1000 RU/s as throughput limit. There is a way to solve this without use an unlimited throughput limit?

Answer (score -1):

```
//your custom error seperate file

class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor(status, message) {
    super();
    this.status = status;
    this.message = message;
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}
module.exports = CustomError;


//put global error handler in app.js

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(err.status || 503).json({
        msg: err.stack || "internal server error",
    });
    next();
});

/// handle error in any function using catch block

.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    return next(new CustomError(500, "my custom error"));
    next();
  })
  
  //hope this should solve issue
```

Comment: tested code in my app runs perfectly

Comment: How would this solve the issue? This is just a custom error handler.